# Vue react to Setting array of an Object to another array and seeing reactive changes

Tags: vue.js

I have a v-data-table on vue, which gets data and dynamically adds and deltes rows based on the incoming object of arrays, Vue is reactive to adding and deleting but doesn't seem to react to array replace.

My function to add, delete and replace is the setup the following way:

```
function update_helper(update_obj, dataObject, colObject) {
  update_obj.Data.forEach((item) => {
    if (typeof item.RowData !== 'undefined'){
      let temp_list = updateRow(item, colObject);
      temp_list.forEach((row_obj) => {
        var found = dataObject.find(Element => Element.RowID === row_obj.RowID);
        if (typeof found !== 'undefined'){
          //Replace
          var found = dataObject.findIndex(Element => Element.RowID === item.RowID);
          //console.log(row_obj);
          //console.log(dataObject[found]);
          dataObject[found] = row_obj;
        }
        else{
          // Add
          dataObject.push(row_obj);
        }
      });
    }
    else if (typeof item.RowData === 'undefined') {
      // Delete
      var found = dataObject.findIndex(Element => Element.RowID === item.RowID);
      dataObject = dataObject.splice(found, 1);
    }
  });
}
```

The function keeps track of the row Id . My replace function `dataObject[found] = rowObj` works but isn't reactive, i.e the change can only be seen when I switch tabs or refresh the page.
How do I workaround this.

Comment: are you using the dataObject on the DOM?

Comment: As per your method, its just a argument which has the life scope only within the function

Comment: I don´t see any reactive data properties there. Can you explain your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing it as argument, you could better have it as a `data` variable like

```
data() {
 return {
  dataObject: [],
 }
}
```

and then define your function inside the methods section like

```
methods: {
 update_helper(update_obj, colObject) {
  update_obj.Data.forEach((item) => {
    if (typeof item.RowData !== 'undefined'){
      let temp_list = updateRow(item, colObject);
      temp_list.forEach((row_obj) => {
        var found = dataObject.findIndex(Element => Element.RowID === row_obj.RowID);
        if (found !== -1){
          this.dataObject[found] = row_obj;
        }
        else{
          // Add
          this.dataObject.push(row_obj);
        }
      });
    }
    else if (typeof item.RowData === 'undefined') {
      // Delete
      var found = this.dataObject.findIndex(Element => Element.RowID === item.RowID);
      dataObject = this.dataObject.splice(found, 1);
    }
  });
 }
}
```

If possible you can declare the colObject also in the `data()` section

Note: If you observe the above function body, I would have accessed the `dataObject` using `this` operator.